# Android onTouchListener not working, works only at the Padding area

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I'm definitely doing something wrong. I have a `ReclyclerView` and the each cell has a XML home_cells.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/home_cv"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            ......
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                ....
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                   ...
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_ratingbar_full_material" />

                <LinearLayout
                   ......
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                       .....
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                       ....
                        android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColor" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                   ....
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <!--<lay-->
</LinearLayout>
```

I have an adapter... everything works fine..... no problem at all.

BUT, when i try to implement onClickLister to complete cell view `mView` IT DOES NOT WORK. If I touch in the corner ( where i have padding) IT WORKS.

I have no idea what is happening. If i set listener to every element in the cell it works... but not the whole cell.

Below is my viewHolder

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        CardView cv;
        ImageView icon;
        TextView heading;
        TextView subheading;
        View mView;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);


            Log.d(TAG, "setting images and items");
            mView=itemView;
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_cv);
            icon =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_rv_icon);
            heading =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            subheading =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subhead);
            icon.setOnClickListener(this); // Working
            mView.setOnClickListener(this); // NOT working
            mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                    // NOT Working
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //
            Log.d(TAG,"on click");
            if(clickListener!=null){
                Log.d(TAG,"listner notnull");
                clickListener.itemClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
            }

        }


    }


    public interface RVClickListener{
        //OnClick will work, but for better coding standard i made this listener to call the onclick from the fragment it self..
        public void itemClick(View view, int position );


    }
```

Comment: On `mView` do you want to implement an` onClickListener` or an onTouchListener? Also, are you sure that it does not work? Do you print any statements in there? Also, what is  the `clickListener` variable? Where do you initialize that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few hours of struggle if finally fixed it. Here is the problem.

Since my layout has child views (layouts) the onclicklistener is being captured by them.

So solved it by a simple solution. I turned off the clickable for all the child views and applied the click listener to the parent.

To all the child views:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped me fix a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **longClickable = "true"** from every child view of the CardView Layout

Comment: When you use **longClickable = "true"** for any childView of the CardView layout, they take all the area of the layout for onClick and the click stops to work on the main CardView. Removing this and adding **OnClickable = "true"** in the parent CardView layout solves this problem. Hope it helps...